# DEVKIT V1 - sketch fails to run when microprocessor mounted on breakout

Tags: esp32

Kind of an ambitious early Arduino development project (I'm relatively new). I'm a coder, Using `VSCode` and `PlatformIO`, I can upload code to board, which runs a web server. Serial port monitor (logging) allows for ensuring the setup() and loop() run as designed. Web page does all it should.

Now for greater connection to sensors, etc.  Bread boarding went well. My issue is trying to get a more permanent setup running, so now I'm adding a breakout board to reduce the amount of soldering.

The sketch runs only when the microprocessor is not connected to anything but the computer (Mac) via USB cable. When I attach the ESP32 to a breakout board, and continue to monitor the serial port for my logging, the port monitor in VSCode connects as before, but nothing is coming from the ESP32 -- no Serial.println() from setup() or loop(). Pull the ESP32 out of the breakout board and all things, including the logging, run as previously described.

Using Amazon links, the breakout board, purchased in Nov,2023 is [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B82BBKCY) and the ESP32, purchased in Oct,2020 (older) is [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B086MJGFVV)

Is there something I'm missing as to how breakout boards are to be used??

I usually have been more self-serve and try to get answers from Google, but I'm not finding much in this arena related to my specific question... I read Stack Overflow nearly daily, haven't really posted here before...

Comment: Do you see any serial output if you connect your computer to the breakout board's USB port, rather than the ESP32's?  It's not clear from the product descriptions just how the two USB ports are supposed to interact.